# display the customer name & location who previously bought the product on product page block

Tags: magento-1.9, product

**I want to display the customer's name, location and date who bought the product previously on the product page**,

can anybody tell me how to do it,

please provide me the code for the same

Answer (score 0):

Yes for this, you will need 
 1. Order data

So to load order data by product,

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){

    //Here add your logic to match with your current product id
    if($currentProductId == $item->getProductId()){

        $customer = $order->getCustomer();
        //Now you have got the customer object 

        //so you can fetch details which you want by your logic
```